# In CruiseControl.Net, how can i pass the developer's username who checked in code to another project?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

In CC.Net, I have a Build project that gets triggered whenever a developer checks in code. I know this project has the developer's username, which is used in the publisher section to send an email notification. 
I have a nightly test project that get's triggered when the Build project succeeds.

**Is there a way I can pass the developer's username from the Build project to the nightly test project?**

I searched online and all I got was people talking about how to use the developer's username to send an email, and about including the regexConverter tag. But no information on my question was available.

Thanks,
Al

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this scenario we have the [Modification Reader Task](http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Modification_Reader_Task).

The Project that is triggered after each commit should use the [Modification Writer Task](http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Modification_Writer_Task) to write a file containing all modifications.

Then the nightly project can read this file with the Modification Reader Task. Check out the [Notes section](http://cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Modification_Reader_Task#Notes) for further information.